# Installing a case fan: What to do when there's no spare 3-pin and no Molexes at all?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, fan

My fan came with a 3-pin connector and a little extension cord to piggyback on a Molex if necessary. It seems that the only kind of power connector my PSU has is the ATX 1.3 (i.e. SATA), and there's only one 3-pin on the mobo which is being used by the CPU heatsink fan.

How can I supply power to my fan?

[Edit] Thank you to @Moab! To summarize my use of their solution below: I'm plugging one of my PSU's SATA connectors into [this](http://www.performance-pcs.com/catalog/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=20580) SATA-to-Molex adapter, which plugs into my fan's included 3-pin-to-Molex-tee extension cord, which plugs into [this](http://www.performance-pcs.com/catalog/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=26171) Molex-to-SATA adapter, which plugs into the device that was originally supplied directly by the above-mentioned SATA connector. (The PSU had no spare SATA connectors, either.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use a molex splitter

[http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Molex-Power-Supply-Splitter/dp/B001PI9AAC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001PI9AAC)

or a Sata to molex adapter if you have No molex connectors.
http://www.performance-pcs.com/catalog/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=20580